# How would I add a date range query in my current MySQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question how do I add a query for a date range here in my MySQL query. The date is generated only.

Here is my Query:

```
SELECT TS.id AS TSid, employeeid, `date` AS date_d, TS.TI1 AS TI1, TS.TO1 AS TO1,
                            CONCAT(E.lastName,', ',E.firstName,' ',E.middleInitial,'.') AS 'fullname',

                            (TIME_TO_SEC(CAST(TS.`TI1` AS time))/3600) AS 'timeinint',                  
                            (TIME_TO_SEC(CAST(TS.`TO1` AS time))/3600) AS 'timeoutint',
                            E.startDate, C.companyName, B.branchName,
                            R.mon, R.tue, R.wed, R.thu, R.fri, R.sat, R.sun
                    FROM timeschedule AS TS
                    LEFT JOIN  employee AS E ON TS.employeeid = E.id
                    LEFT JOIN  company AS C ON E.companyid = C.id
                    LEFT JOIN  branch AS B ON E.branchid = B.id
                    LEFT JOIN restday AS R ON R.id = E.restDayid
                    WHERE TS.`show` = '1'  
                    ORDER BY employeeid ASC
```

HEre is how I get the input:

```
$mfrom = $this->input->get('mfroma');  //From: Month
$yfrom = $this->input->get('yfroma');  //From: Year
$yto = $this->input->get('ytoa');      //To : Year
```

Comment: in your WHERE. WHERE TS.show = 1 AND date BETWEEN one_date AND another_date

Comment: what is date range you want to display?

Comment: are month and year the only date filters you have? pretty broad terms I would've thought...

Comment: @scrowler: yes month and year filter only

Answer (score 0):

With the fields you've specified (from month and year and to year) you can add these conditions into your `WHERE` clause. I'm going to use the `E.startDate` field for this example:

```
$sql = "-- your query here...
    WHERE
        TS.`show` = '1'
        AND MONTH(E.startDate) >= " . $mfrom . "
        AND YEAR(E.startDate) BETWEEN " . $yfrom . " AND " . $yto . "
    ORDER BY employeeid ASC";
```

**Docs:** 
- [`MONTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)
- [`YEAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)

**Note:** PHP parses variables inside double quotes, but I personally prefer to keep PHP variables outside of them.